# Is there Definitive way line breaks / special characters should be stored in a MySQL text cell?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, character-encoding

This may look like a duplicate question but all answers point to multiple solutions. Is this the case and just down to preference/usage?

I've gone around in circles with all option.
`nl2br` (before & after insert), `stripslashes`, `str_replace`, `Magic Quotes`

What should I be seeing in my phpmyadmin cell when looking at a block of text.

1. `This is some text
   Some text`
2. `This is some text<br>Some text`
3. `This is some text<br />Some text`
4. `This is some text\r\nSome text`
5. `?`

Simply to see, new lines, special characters and quote marks displayed correctly on demand, whether that be as plain text or within a textarea etc. I still feel like I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: You are. Just store them as they are using a prepared statement and only convert / encode them when you output to a medium that requires that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a principle.  A database should be considered a repository for data.  Not for formatting.

By using `<br>` in a `VARCHAR`/`TEXT`, you are locking it into being an HTML page.

On the other hand, it is reasonable to have linefeeds in strings.  In which case, do *just* that -- `\n`.  Then, if you need to display it on a web page via PHP, use `nl2br()`.  If you need to do something different, you are at least starting with something simple and 'standard' enough, namely the single character `\n`.

Similarly, don't store htmlentities (`&...;`).  Instead correctly establish character sets and use `utf8mb4`.  UTF-8 is generally recognized as the 'right' way to deal with international characters by most software today.  If something deviates from it, then there is at least a 'standard' encoding you are starting from.

You must escape strings (or use prepare / bind) when building `INSERT` statements.  That is a fact-of-life with all languages that involve quoted strings.  But you should not need to do any kind of un-escaping when `SELECTing` the data.